# Example of disjoint sets that are not additive in outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've read that a disadvantage of Lebesgue outer measure is that we can have disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ s.t. $m(A \bigcup B) \neq m(A) + m(B)$, but so far I haven't found any examples... Any examples?, and how is Lebesgue outer measure really different from Lebesgue measure?

Comment: If this is Lebesgue outer measure, you'll need at least one of these to be a nonmeasurable set, because otherwise outer measure equals measure, which is additive over disjoint sets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set A Bernstein set $B\subset[0,1]$ is of full outer measure (=1), and its complement in $[0,1]$ is also a Bernstein set.